# Just update to 14.04 and calculator mssing the mode button

Tags: calculator

When I used the calculator from 12.04, it was very nice and I can switch mode.  But after upgrade to 14.04, somehow the mode button is missing in calculator, just a simple decimal calculator, please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my 14.04 installation Mode is on the menu bar as seen below.

[image]

Comment: yeah, it's on the global menu by default (on the upper left panel) and is hidden until you hover with the cursor

Comment: @bigben you can accept this answer by clicking on the icon to the left to mark this question answered

Comment: You should add a screenshot